# VSCode: Ignore line breaks and white space when cutting with STRG + X

Tags: visual-studio-code

I love VSCode and all of its unique features but theres one thing thats really annoying me lately and I'd love to fix it if possible.

I always cut lines to move them around or insert somewhere else.

Whats annoying me about this feature however is that when I paste the line I cut inside another line, it will insert the text I cut above the line my cursor is currently at.

I recorded two gifs to show what I want vs what VSCode does:

What I want (emacs):

[image]

What I dont want (VSCode):

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: That bothers me too.  If you first select the text you want - so you are not copying the entire line (with line breaks presumably) it works fine.  But that is a bad solution.  There must be something better.